# wp_schedule_single_event does not call my action

Tags: wordpress, cron, scheduled-tasks, hook

wp_schedule_single_event function work in functions.php but does not working in custom plugin file

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_schedule_single_event' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/cron.php'; 
}

add_action('test', 'test_action');
do_action('test');

function test_action() {
    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 10, 'cron' );
    }
}

add_action('cron', 'send_email_cron');
function send_email_cron() {
    // wp_mail() function
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Attach action to `init` or `wp`

```
add_action('wp', 'test_action');
```

So final code:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_schedule_single_event' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/cron.php'; 
}

add_action('init', 'test_action');

function test_action() {
    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 10, 'cron' );
    }
}

add_action('cron', 'send_email_cron');
function send_email_cron() {
    // wp_mail() function
}
```

Comment: Not working.
Why this code work in functions.php but not in custom plugin file?
Maybe i missed something?